# How to Obtain Domain User Name when connecting via SQL Authentication

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, triggers

I have an application which connects to SQL Server 2000 (using a generic SQL Login and SQL Authentication).  I would like to implement some logging via triggers to track data changes.  I can't use `USER_NAME()` because that returns the generic account.

I've poked through `master..sysprocesses` and it doesn't seem to record the username (although it does record the machine name).

Any ideas how, within SQL, to gain access to the username?

(Note: yes, I could pass it in as a variable via the application ... but that would mean I'd have to roll out a new version of the app; I'm trying to do this from within SQL, so I can avoid that, if possible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Simple. SQL Server has no knowledge of the end user with a SQL login *at all*

The same applies if you use a proxy (web server etc) too: you don't know the end user. We use parameters/stored procs to pass in the username from the web server.

I would suggest that you set CONTEXT_INFO in the client which persists for that connection.

Comment: That's as I suspected, thanks.  Unfortunately for me, alas.  I was hoping that somebody had managed it, though, as this answer means that I have to release a new build of several applications to 40+ offices.

Comment: Funny, though: `master..sysprocesses` does record the machine name, so it knows the source of the connection, just not whatever security authentication information is in place *at* that machine.  Seems strange that it wouldn't know who's logged in, because that user must have some privileges in order to establish the connection.  So, the user has a valid security token, but SQL Server just ... doesn't pay any attention to it?  Odd.

Comment: David T. Macknet: The NT login token is not attached to the connection because the client specifies "SQL auth". It is just not available. The NT login token is machine independent too: you can have multiple users from one client.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SYSTEM_USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx)?

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER
```

Comment: Yep.  SQL Server Books Online says: "If the current user is logged in to Microsoft® SQL Server™ using Windows Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the Windows 2000 or Windows NT 4.0 login identification name, for example, DOMAIN\user_login_name. However, if the current user is logged in to SQL Server using SQL Server Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the SQL Server login identification name, for example, sa for a user logged in as sa."  So, in this case I'd get the generic login, which isn't desirable.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible through SQL authentication.